# Calculate DC pulsed Current going into Inverter

Tags: current

Have created a DC battery monitor for a Narrowboat. All the sensors work as exspected except the one measuring the current to the Inverter, which I cannot get to show the correct value. I have tried using a current transducers and also a current transformer. The problem is this a pulsed dc Current created by the switching of the GBT's and I thought you could just calculate the average amplitude of the waveform created. By slicing it then adding together and dividing by the number of slices, but that does not work, does not give correct value.  A multimeter reads what I believe is the correct voltage from the current sensors, and changes as exspected with change in load, and a Clamp DC meter does give the current, but when the ADC in the micontroller reads this same voltage value that the multimeter reads, I get the wrong values.  I tried uploading the graph of values read by the ADC, but

Comment: Consider using a in-line shunt or using the wiring as a shunt and amplifying the signal to determine current

Answer (score 1):

The current transformer measures only the AC current, not the DC. You would need a DC current transducer, like those produced by LEM. You didn't mention the current range you wish to measure.

All measuring inputs need a low pass filter, perhaps this is the problem for voltage meaurment, also a good stable voltage reference to the ADC without noise is required

Comment: Yes I know a Current Transformer is for AC, but it does give quite good readings when a Pulsed DC goes through it which is like a wave form.  Yes I have serveral Lem Current transducers which state are suitable for pulsed DC, I have had long discusstions with the technical department at Lem but they have be unable to tell me how to calculate from the results the current.   I have also tried Honeywell Current Transducers which have a rail to rail supply which Honeywell tell me is required to measure pulsed DC. Range Battery to inverter 0-320amps - Charge  inverter to battery of 0-160amps.

Comment: Transducer for pulsed DC means that it has fast response, the measuring output is almost identical as measured current in amplitude and time. This kind of transducers are used to interface with MCU or DSP for controling the inverter. Your demand would require to know the RMS value of the current. There are ready made transducers look for True RMS DC current transducer, or it would be a good try to add a RC filter at the output of your LEM.